# Drush command to check if Drupal is installed?

Tags: drush

Is there any way to use Drush to determine if Drupal is installed, and have it return true or false? The boolean output would be used elsewhere in a bash script's logic.

Bonus: it needs to work for both Drupal 7 and Drupal 8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ cd /path/to/drupal6or7or8
$ drush status bootstrap | grep -q Successful
```

Then, `$?` will be 0 if Drupal has been installed, or 1 if there is no site, or it does not have a database, or the site has not been installed.

Comment: This does not work anymore with Drush 12. What is recommended now?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @greg_1_anderson answer, I'd like to add that that is sensitive to locale problems. `Successful` will be translated in the output from Drush. To work around this problem, I'd suggest this somewhat dirty workaround:

```
drush status bootstrap | grep -q $(drush php-eval 'if (function_exists("t")) echo t("Successful");') &> /dev/null;
```

As mentioned above, `$?` will be `0` if installed, higher if not.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking for a like for like replacement for `drush status bootstrap` in Drush 12:

```
drush status --field=bootstrap
```

Comment: Upvoted. This is the way. Returns "Successful" if successful, otherwise blank.

Answer (score 0):

As of Drush 12 `drush status bootstrap` does not work anymore.

You can check if there is something in the config table instead:

```
drush sql-query 'SELECT 1 FROM config LIMIT 0,1' > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Return value 0 means Drupal is installed.

Comment: `SELECT 1` or selecting a specific column name should be faster than `SELECT *`.